# Bug Report and Power menu - Bug Report function not working on Nexus 7 Android 4.3

Tags: nexus-7, 4.3-jelly-bean, bug-report-feature

I need to gather log info for QA testing.  The settings menu "Bug Report" and the power menu "Bug Report" functions don't work for me on my Nexus 7 running Jellybean 4.3 (don't know if it ever worked because I just found out about the function).  I get a popup saying "this will take a while..." and after that nothing.  Scanning the file system, I don't see anything that looks like a screen capture, and no mail is sent out.

(I can't get the magic {power/sound up/sound down} button combo to work either). The only way I can collect app logging info is by tethering the nexus 7 and using ADB.

Any idea how to get the new bug report mechanism working or why it's not working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered the solution (at least for my Nexus 7)! Here's what happens:

1. Tap Take Bug Report
2. Take bug report "take a while" popup displays - Tap report
3. After about 30 seconds, the words "bug report captured" appear for about 2 seconds on the left side of the top menu bar (the one with Time and Wi-Fi and other icons)
4. An Android icon then displays on the left side (where downloads and other status indicators display)
5. Swiping down on those icons displays an item "Bug report captured"
6. Tapping on the item brings up a "Complete action using" popup that includes Gmail
7. Tapping the Gmail icon allow you to send the bug report text and its associated screen capture to yourself

Pretty nice, but very easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've read, `Make Bug Report` is supposed to e-mail the bug report to the GMail account that's tied to your device.

I tried it, but I didn't get any emails. I will update this answer if I find anything new.